# is there any other options to save my page as jpeg?

Tags: image, button, save

i want to save the image with span value but its not working [I WANT LIKE THIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWsyW.jpg)
but its not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Save Area as JPG</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="captureArea">

    <p><span id="dateDisplay"></span></p>
    <p><span id="expDisplay"></span></p>
    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/V3b95kB/GP.jpg" alt="Challan Image">

  </div>
  <button id="saveButton">Save as JPG</button>

  <!-- Include necessary libraries -->
  <script src="https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/2.0.0/FileSaver.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

its not working properly